# sitemap for bing?

Tags: search-engine

Google has the sitemap.xml and Yahoo the urllist.txt that you can place in the root of your website to facilitate the indexation process. Does Bing has something similar ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Bing FAQ](http://help.live.com/help.aspx?mkt=en-us&project=wl_webmasters) tells about sitemaps and use http://www.sitemaps.org/ protocol.